# Overlay network in docker swarm not working

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, docker-swarm

This is my setup https://github.com/czpo/docker-reverse-proxy

So there is a simple nginx/php stack on the worker and when I put a reverse proxy on the worker node it will load that site in the browser. But if I put the RP on a manager (like in the repo) I get a "host not found in upstream" error 502 even though I have an overlay network that connects the RP with Nginx/php.